# Compile Go tip with extra packages

Tags: go

I'd like to try out the `exp/regexp` package. Currently Go tip's `./all.bash` command compiles including only `exp/regexp/syntax`. I've been looking around the makefiles and I see it builds a `Make.deps` but couldn't figure out how it selects the packages that are included. What should I change to build Go with `exp/regexp`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Duh, it was right in front of my eyes! Add the package dir to `src/pkg/Makefile`:

```
DIRS=\
    archive/tar\
    archive/zip\
    asn1\
    ...
    exp/regexp\
    ...
```